# Allergy symptoms after attic insulation replacement

Tags: insulation, attic, fiberglass

Had my 20 year old attic insulation replaced with new blown-in white fiberglass by professionals yesterday.

Family is now having significant allergy symptoms especially when central air is. Purifier is all full blast, not helping when AC is on. Reported Air quality is 60-70%

Is this normal? Will symptoms resolve soon? Do i just need to open windows with aC on? Tips/advice appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: There are natural insulation materials available which may not cause the allergy symptoms, but just the work may be the issue by raising the dust already present (dust is old skin amongst other things)... Also, where is the air intake and is it filtered?

Comment: Your air purifier should not have an inlet in your roof space. Either its just dust or you have a faulty air installation

Comment: Having the air purifier, fans, etc, blowing may be prolonging the issue by keeping the air moving and not allowing the particulates in the air to settle back to the ground where they've been for most of the last 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

I am very sensitive to insulation materials, and will often be sneezing for days after working with insulation in a house. I always wear a P100 mask while doing the work. But even the dust around the house or on my clothes will trigger allergies, for example, when I take my mask off to eat lunch.

This is all to say that you should open all the doors and windows, do a deep cleaning of the house, wash all blankets and sheets, and change the A/C filter.